# How can I parse/compile/resolve the contents of contained html in my angularjs directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I parse/compile/resolve the contents of contained html in my directives.

The directive in question is:

```
angular.module('transclude', [])
 .directive('heading', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
        scope: {
            cls: '@'
        },
      template: '<h1 ng-transclude></h1>'
    };
});
```

and the html to accompany it:

```
<div ng-app="transclude">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <heading cls="beans">
          <span class="{{cls}}">{{cls}}</span>
      </heading>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've created the following very simplified plunker to demonstrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ys9fekss/

As you can see, I am expecting the html which is contained within my directive to have the {{cls}} tags on both the attribute and the contained html to be replaced with the literal string 'beans'.

I've been struggling with this all day - I've looked at scoping, compiling, link functions - you name it, and to no avail.

What I'm trying to do is create a validator directive which can wrap any type of field.

What do I have to do to get angular to parse that field's html?

**UPDATE:** Since I'm still struggling with this, I've posted my actual HTML (modified for the solution given below) showing the problem with the shared scope:

http://jsfiddle.net/hwsqsxf3/

In the above example, setting scope: true stops the repeated values, but then stops the name="" attribute being parsed!

What I need is both of these things... at once!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this seems to be the fix, although it is a bit inelegant:

http://jsfiddle.net/ywksgocm/

This includes two-way binding of the model, and inherited and augmented parent scope (for abritrary controller scope access).

The key to this is:

`myScope.$new();`

If there are any ways to improve this, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps a different aproach is what you need, a directive with shared scope (not isolated like yours) but with the ability to create new values to the scope, that way you can use the directive many times in  your app but with different values in each one of them:

```
<div ng-app="transclude">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <heading cls="beans" target="tar">
          <span class="{{tar}}">{{tar}}</span>
      </heading>
  </div>
</div>
```

// the `target` attribute will be your scope value (theres no need to be even declared in the controller)

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.foo = 'Bar';
}

angular.module('transclude', [])
 .directive('heading', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<h1 ng-transclude></h1>',
        link: function(scope, el, attr){
            scope[attr.target] = attr.cls;
        }
    };
});
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwsqsxf3/)

Comment: The problem seems to be that I need an isolated scope - I use the fields multiple times on the page and now all my fields have the same name.

Comment: Your solution partially works - but I've added my actual code so that you can see the problem it also causes: http://jsfiddle.net/hwsqsxf3/

Comment: You send my own fiddle in your comment you need to modify, fork and then send otherwise it looks the same as the original

Comment: Whoops. Didn't realise it wasn't forking it automatically like one of the other ones I used.

I've added and accepted the answer with the fixed directive in - thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved my own problem - with much help from Strife86 and [This blog](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/)

My solution is here. It's not very elegant - not sure if this is a fault of the way directives work or a fault of me. If there is a more elegant way I'd love to hear it.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwsqsxf3/)

The directive's code is bascally:

```
.directive('validatingField', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            label: '@',
            field: '@',
            labelWidth: '@',
            fieldWidth: '@',
            error: '=',
            ngModel: '='
        },
        templateUrl: "validating-field.html",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {

          transcludeFn(scope, function(clone, scp) {
            element.find('ng-transclude').replaceWith(clone);
          });

        }
    };
}]);
```

Binding ngModel was the most difficult thing and I'm not happy repeating elements constantly, but right now I've burned 1.5 days to get here so I'm not really in the mood for experimenting!

Comment: Haven't solved it. Select boxes now can't find anything in the parent scope such as their option lists.